# Typescript get object's key name with type safety

Tags: typescript

How do I get a key from an object or Record with type safety?
The below example prints `dog max` but `dog` is a hardcoded string. Can I remove the hardcoding somehow?

```
type pettype = 'dog' | 'cat'

const pets: Record<pettype, string> = {
  'dog': 'max',
  'cat': 'juliet',
}

// Print "dog max" without hardcoding 'dog'
console.log('dog', pets.dog)
// Looking at something like nameof(pets.dog)
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "type safety for 'dog' key". `pets.dog` is typesafe - it has been established by your Record type that `dog` is a key on `pets`. If you mean that the value of `pets.dog` should be typesafe (i.e. always equal to `'max'`, not `string`) then you need an interface which exactly matches `pets`, not a Record.

Comment: Within the console.log, I have the string `dog`. I don't want it hardcoded. I want compile-time safety if in the future I want to rename that property to something else.

Comment: It is already typesafe. For example, if you type `Dog` instead of `dog`, you will get compile error because `Dog` is not in the type `pettype`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing `nameof(pets.dog)` which is the same as `nameof('max')` take the pettype as the argument to `nameof`

```js
const nameof(pet: pettype) => {
  console.log(pet, pets[pet])
}
```

if you did want to look up the type of pet by its name you should switch the key and value of pets.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use the string literal "dog" later in your code and you want to use something like the constant string variable, you can define `const` variables.

For example,

```js
const DOG = "dog";
const CAT = "cat";

type pettype = typeof DOG | typeof CAT;

const pets: Record<pettype, string> = {
  [DOG]: 'max',
  [CAT]: 'juliet',
};

console.log(DOG, pets[DOG])
```

Note that the `typeof` operator is used when defining the union type, and the brackets are used when the variables are used as keys.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you want, but from your example I assume you want to print `"dog max"` by only passing the object without the `"dog"` string.

```
type PetType = 'dog' | 'cat';

const pets: Record<PetType, string> = {
  'dog': 'max',
  'cat': 'juliet',
}

function nameof(name: string) {
  // find key by value
  const [petType] = Object.entries(pets).find(([_petType, petName]) => petName === name) || []
  console.log(petType, name);
}

nameof(pets.dog); // dog max
nameof(pets.cat); // cat juliet
nameof("foo"); // undefined foo
```

However this can become an issue if there are pets with same name

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAChwBVzQLxQOQBMD2BzdUAPhgMYCGw6A3AFA0nYB2AzsFJMMwFxQBKEDAE6YAPHETIANFFaCAlo1wA+KGgDeNKBhz4e6ALZkAHukmbSFdHoBWAVwA2c+KZoBfOgDNbjEsDlMoRjJ9CGwPAAogkJ5ZBVwASigNLQYWNgBtDiRIAF1VKAB5ACNrAWAAOghGYHkIZnCOZnjyjwVMcPD0gH0sqXZ4ADlgiBzElBUOIZDVFDQoiETCYnSc81TmbHsIcvs8BvhsiGl5+Np3Gnmw-c5ynVOoAHoHqB0oQyML4avG8vJge6eUD+UDsjngnxCVwARB5sNgoQDnt5MBBWowIJgoLDsEA)

---

Or stricter if pet name is a defined / static value:

```
// Generic type to get object value as union type
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

type PetType = 'dog' | 'cat';
type PetName = 'max' | 'juliet';

const pets: Record<PetType, PetName> = {
  'dog': 'max',
  'cat': 'juliet',
}

function nameof(name: ValueOf<typeof pets>) {
  const [petType] = Object.entries(pets).find(([_petType, petName]) => petName === name) || []
  console.log(petType, name);
}

nameof(pets.dog); // dog max
nameof(pets.cat); // cat juliet
nameof("foo"); // "foo" is not assignable to parameter of type ValueOf<Record<PetType, PetName>>
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/PTAEHEFMDtIJwJYGNQBcCeAHSaD2oBzSVUXAIwCtIkSA3AQwBsBXHegZ1GegV2jSyQAUBmygAak1YB5AGYAeACoA+UAF5QigNoBrSOlyzNAXQDcQkYNAAFYoqsaA5ABNcBR6AA+oR0nqpHc1EcW1QAOXoAWxwnSPoADw9vRwpmRgRiRwskPnYSbFR2AC5QACVqXDhneVD7bAAaG2II6NUNAG8hUB9XdxLHOMT6rp8-AP7U9MzhgF8LWW4aXn5oKMhDAApV6JLJFkg5eWDDUAL2ZQBKUE7unOg80C0CushjdVBpSmpUADoYVEQkHYGzOFx+sgQ0GcGw2WgA+s9BI0Ci1Xlc1KoUWt1GoNNtIFdPN4tMYRnd2LhGJAfow3CC7EjQPiLuY5kJ8Zszj9eizQCBQL1QIN2WtOcR2D8xrz+WNQJMMqgRdFNgAiWS4XAq6VgNUalWgBCcaC4EgcdgIAirMhUvCnehwNaoeCkIzBCRSA4Kco5Ko1BkNJrhNbKZRAA)

Or cleaner version:

```
// Generic type to get object value as union type
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

const pets = {
  dog: 'max',
  cat: 'juliet',
} as const;

// You can also extract the type if needed
type PetKeys = keyof typeof pets; // "dog" | "cat"
type PetNames = ValueOf<typeof pets>; // "max" | "juliet"

function nameof(name: ValueOf<typeof pets> /* or PetNames */) {
  const [petType] = Object.entries(pets).find(([_petType, petName]) => petName === name) || []
  console.log(petType, name);
}

nameof(pets.dog); // dog max
nameof(pets.cat); // cat juliet
nameof("foo"); // Error because "foo" != "max" or "juliet"
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=59#code/PTAEHEFMDtIJwJYGNQBcCeAHSaD2oBzSVUXAIwCtIkSA3AQwBsBXHegZ1GegV2jSyQAUBmygAak1YB5AGYAeACoA+UAF5QigNoBrSOlyzNAXQDcQoUj7sS2VJw0BvIaFAATXAQBcoAOQBbegAPXwAaF1AkelQfXwpmRgRiMKEAX1AOSOtUcyEQUABNXGZI+n4mdnxIINQ4eho0AAscURwEI1hINy6RQVAABWIAaX0HUD0DI1bDUDt2U1B8gCIPAiXQAB9QJajUJd6xQdQAOXp-SDHJFkg5eWmjOeUF5cCg9a2l+MTifaFZbhovH40DOkEMAAoQecfFcZAp7rNiOxVMAAFSkOADYinc6cVHAACUoGcris0BsoC0dkUgmM6lA0ko1FQADoYLUkuxwXMCSzZAhoG5weCtAB9amCUKIk6g4xEtSqOw4nBqVWgKGQIkbLZaYwRMmVRiQFmMTzc4g07BSjUE8ypCwaiFzFmrW2LMCrUCvISO2Tm+ws3Zu-K7UBfJKoH2giFLWS4XBLYNgACicDguExZGo9GY7Bwsfj6wAhBolq91hntuGfkA)